# bison grammar execution order

Tags: bison, yacc

I have a grammar like this:

```
A : a B {int i = 0; printf("%d",i);};

B: and b B {i++; printf("%d",i);}
 | %empty 
 ;
```

input a and b and b and b

output : 1230

my question is : how to change the order of execution to have 0123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use left recursion instead of right recursion.

Bison executes actions exactly in the way you tell it to. Each non-terminal's action is executed exactly as soon as the non-terminal is completed.

If you use a right-recursive rule:

```
B: "and" b B
```

then the outer `B`'s action, which prints the semantic value of `b`, executes after the inner `B`'s action, which prints the semantic values of the `b`s which follow.

A much more natural way to write that grammar, which has the further advantage of producing correct associativity, is:

```
A: a
 | A "and" b
```

Moreover, the actions in that grammar will execute left-to-right, because the inner `A`'s action is executed as soon as it is complete, which is before the associated `b` has even been seen.